# Paper size: Printer Properties vs Page Setup

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, printer

When printing a document from a MS Office or another program one can select paper size from two places:
 - Page Set-up (Page Layout in MS Word 2007)
 - Printer Properties

What's the difference?
What if these two settings contradict each other.

Answer (score 2):

Printer Properties are the physical dimensions of the page in centimeters or inches.

Page setup is for many types of data. The one that corresponds to the above is the dimensions of the margins on the four sides of the page. The top and bottom margins include the header and footer.

In other words: Once Word knows the physical dimensions of the page from the printer, it can calculate the page's layout using the page's setup. Different sections in the document can have different page setups, but all sections are printed using the one and same printer page size.

Answer (score 1):

***Printer Properties*** :Checking and Changing your Default Paper Size

***Page Set-up*** :Checking and Changing for that particular document or temporary  Paper Size

if you are changing in the page set-up then that document be considered with that page size , other wise it will take from the default size .